# Competitive audit

Tags: user-expectation, user-research, research, app, competitive-analysis

I am trying to conduct a competitive audit for a project I am working on.
I would like to find competitors for a bus seat reservation app, but the country where the app will be shipped doesn't have any direct competitors providing such service, neither has any indirect competitors!
I wonder what to do on this case?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should determine why do you need a competitive audit. If this is a new concept and there are no direct competitors on the market, there are several research methods to try, but in most of the cases these are market and not UX related, so it should be done by the business and not by a UX designer.

**Best Practice Research** is the so-called one of the important pillars of evidence-based design. In such cases, the most important task is to collect and process the research results. In the course of the Best Practice research, we map the features of domestic and international competitors and websites and companies providing similar services, which we then document with screenshots and text. It means, that during this research you examine the solutions and interfaces used by competitors, and even products with similar features, solutions you want to include in your app, and map out the solutions that work well in practice. So you don't have to look just for a competitor. A product what has a seat reservation feature is also a very good example. It can be a train, movie, or even a hairdresser reservation. The important thing is finding best practices for the job story (reservation) you have in your product.

**4 steps of best practice research:**

1. Definition of research area (e.g. websites, applications, services, etc.).
2. Gather the websites you want to test (URLs and, if necessary, access to the user interface).
3. According to the analysis criteria, all sub-pages, functions and content of the website should be examined.
4. In the meantime, screenshots must be created and saved.

Answer (score 1):

You should also have added what attributes you look for in a business/product to determine them as competitors. Nevertheless, @davidtoltesy covered it all, best practice research is what you can go with -- you should mark his reply as the correct answer.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than like an answer. You will be able to comment once you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Design is universal. Modified and molded to its local context but never the less  a universal language. Why restrict yourself to the country?